# Ninject Factory Pattern and Bindings

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, factory

I am trying to implement the Ninject.Extensions.Factory pattern and my program is telling me my bindings aren't right, but I can't figure out why. I keep getting an "Error activating IHashable. No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable" exception thrown. The relevant areas of my code are below:

```
public interface IHashable
{
    FileInfo File { get; }

    string ComputeHash();
}

public interface IHashableFactory
{
    IHashable GetNew(FileInfo file);
}

public class MD5ChecksumProvider : IHashable
{
    private FileInfo _file;

    public FileInfo File
    {
        get { return _file; }
    }

    public MD5ChecksumProvider(FileInfo file)
    {
        if (file == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("file");

        _file = file;
    }

    public string ComputeHash()
    {
        // implementation
    }
}

public class AppFileProvider : IAppFileProvider
{
    private IHashableFactory _hashFactory;

    public IHashableFactory HashProvider
    {
        get { return _hashFactory; }
    }

    public AppFileProvider(IHashableFactory hashProviderFactory)
    {
        _hashFactory = hashProviderFactory;
    }

    public string GetChecksum(FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        var hasher = _hashFactory.GetNew(fileInfo);
        return hasher.ComputeHash();
    }
}

public class BindingProviders : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IHashable>()
            .To<MD5ChecksumProvider>();
    }
}

public class BindingFactories : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IHashableFactory>()
            .ToFactory();
    }
}

// my DI container
public sealed class Container : IDisposable
{
    private bool _isDisposed;
    private IKernel _kernel;
    private BindingFactories _bindingFactories;
    private BindingObjects _bindingObjects;
    private BindingProviders _bindingProviders;

    public Container()
    {
        _isDisposed = false;

        _bindingFactories = new BindingFactories();
        _bindingObjects = new BindingObjects();
        _bindingProviders = new BindingProviders();

        _kernel = new StandardKernel(_bindingObjects, _bindingProviders, _bindingFactories);
    }

    public T Get<T>()
    {
        return _kernel.Get<T>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // nothing worth seeing
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // nothing worth seeing
    }
}

// the program (composition root)
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        using (var container = new Container())
        {
            var fileProvider = container.Get<IAppFileProvider>();

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                string hash = fileProvider.GetChecksum(storePath, file); // this line throws "Error activating IHashable. No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like my bindings are setup correctly but I must be missing something obvious. Any ideas why I'm getting the exception from the above code?

Comment: `BindingObjects` class is missing from the example code you've posted.

Comment: I didn't include that class because it wasn't relevant to the issue I was having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by a feature of Ninject.Extensions.Factory.
It treats methods which start with `Get` differently from those which don't.
If you rename `IHashableFactory.GetNew` to `Create` or `Make` everything works fine.

The "`Get`" feature is described [here](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/12/31/ninject-extensions-factory-introduction):

> The default instace provider of the extension has the convention that it tries to return an instance using a named binding whenever a method starts with “Get”. E.g. IFoo GetMySpecialFoo() is equal to
>
> `resolutionRoot.Get<IFoo>("MySpecialFoo");`

---

Since i think this is not obvious to the user and the exception isn't helpful at all in this regard, i have filed an issue report [here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/issues/24)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that's what was caused me hours of frustration. Very helpful, thanks!